# Getting the emulator to run

Tags: android-studio

Please i am having issues with getting the emulator to work on my code. I have the below code and i want to be able to play the sound when i click on the button i have created on emulator but whenever i run the code the emulator does not pop up instead the media player pop up and the sound gets played on its own. Please help. Is there something i am doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

**Below is my code**

public class Sound extends ActionBarActivity {

```
MediaPlayer Sound;
private static Button btnsound;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sound);
    Sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.coins);
    playsound();
}

public void playSound (View view) {
    Sound.start();
}

public void playsound(){
    btnsound=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_sound);

    btnsound.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
            public void onClick (View v){

                    Sound.start();

                }
});
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_sound, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

The activity.xml

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btnsound"
    android:onClick="playSound"
    android:id="@+id/button_sound"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    android:layout_marginTop="154dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure the sound plays on It's own, you have inside `onCreate` a call to the method `playsound()`, delete that line and call this method inside the Button Listener so it stays like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sound);
    Sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.coins);
    btnsound = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_sound);

    btnsound.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
                playSound();
            }  
    });
}
public void playSound () {
    Sound.start();
}
```

You have a little mess with declarations and functions, watch out.

Comment: Ok. Thanks so so much. It really helped. I am learning gradually. Also if i want to have more than one sound in should i just have different methods for each sound or what is the best thing i should do.

Comment: That's a good idea, in your case I would probably do the same